# GitLab merge request blocked with pipeline must succeed, but no pipeline is set up

Tags: gitlab, merge-request

New to GitLab.
I’m trying to merge a branch into a dev branch in a repo, however, the MR is blocked with the following message. However, this repo does not have a pipeline set up (screenshot). Plus, all my MR has been ok until this point. I don’t recall changing any git workflow. Any suggestion or idea on how to resolve this? Googling and ChatGPT haven’t helped much.

[image: [MR blocked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAuZb.png)]

[image: [No pipeline set up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNjNk.png)]

I've tried with other branch, they all have the same issue:
"Merge blocked: pipeline must succeed. Push a commit that fixes the failure or learn about other solutions."

Answer (score 0):

I guess you may enabled a settings, which require a successful pipeline for the source branch.
Please check if the **Pipelines must succeed** setting is turned on or not.
If it is turned on, you have to have a successful pipeline for the source branch. Simply just turn it off if you do not need it.

According to the documentation you can find the settings: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/merge_when_pipeline_succeeds.html#require-a-successful-pipeline-for-merge